# Add custom function to objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I want add new function after i have created objects . I try write some code but it not right.
//
Sorry my description don't clear. I want after i create an object i can add function for this object to do something. Hope someone can understand my english :(

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7LnLerdt/

```js
function Add(a,b){
    var _self = this;
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
}

Add.prototype.doAdd = function(){
       var rs = this.a+this.b;
      
        if(rs < 10){
            this.lessThanTen();
        }else{
            this.moreThanTen();
        }
    };

Add.prototype.moreThanTen = function(callback) {
 if(callback){
  callback.call(this);
 }
};

Add.prototype.lessThanTen = function(callback) {
 if(callback){
  callback.call(this);
 }
};

var add = new Add();

add.moreThanTen(function(){
    console.log("moreThanTen");
});

add.lessThanTen(function(){
    console.log("lessThanTen")
});

add.doAdd();
```

Comment: what do you want to do in the code?

Comment: "but it not right" is not a good description of a problem. Please do include the code in the question, and edit the question to explain what doesn't work and why, i.e. what you expected to happen.

Comment: I edited the code so it is in the post where it belongs.

Comment: I want after i create an object i can add function for this object to do something.

Answer (score 0):

The code where you are "assigning" callbacks is not how it works. It just executes the method, it does not magically just assign the callback. The callbacks would need to be passed into the doAdd method or you need to assign the callbacks in a different manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add properties to object use this code instead:

```
function Add(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

If you want to add callbacks use this:

```
Add.prototype.addCallbacks(less, more) {
   this.less = less;
   this.more = more;
};

Add.prototype.moreThanTen = function(callback) {
    if(this.more){
        this.more.call(this);
    }
};

Add.prototype.lessThanTen = function(callback) {
    if(this.less){
        this.less.call(this);
    }
};
```

and then

```
var add = new Add();

add.addCallbacks(function(){
    console.log("lessThanTen")
}, function(){
    console.log("moreThanTen");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. First, using `var` will declare a *local* variable, so it will not be accessible outside that function. If you want to create a *member* variable, use `this.` instead (as jcubic pointed out).

```
function Add(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

Second, you are not adding the callbacks correctly. Your code is executing the callback immediately, but (I think) what you really want to do is save the callback and execute it later.

```
function Add(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.moreThanTenCallbacks = [];
    this.lessThanTenCallbacks = [];
}

Add.prototype.moreThanTen = function(callback) {
    moreThanTenCallbacks.push(callback);
};

Add.prototype.lessThanTen = function(callback) {
    lessThanTenCallbacks.push(callback);
};

Add.prototype.executeCallback = function(callbacks) {
    for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; ++i) {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }
};

Add.prototype.doAdd = function() {
    var rs = this.a + this.b;
    if (rs < 10) {
        this.executeCallback(this.lessThanTenCallbacks);
    } else {
        // NOTE: this will execute moreThanTen callbacks even if the result equals 10!
        // Are you sure that is what you want?
        this.executeCallback(this.moreThanTenCallbacks);
    }
};
```